# Sentence structure : complement

Tags: sentence-structure

> He could not bring himself to avoid answering the teacher's question.

Is this a S+V+O+C sentence pattern?

Subject: He
Verb: bring
object: himself
Complement: to avoid

what does "***answering the teacher's question***" represent?

I am not sure, but my guess is TWO ***Os*** or TWO ***Cs***
the gerund "**answering**" is the ***object*** of the verb "**avoid**"
or is it the ***complement*** of the verb "**avoid**"?

and "**the teacher's question**" is the ***object*** of the gerund "**answering**"
or is it the ***complement*** of the gerund "**answering**"?

If either of the above is correct,
Then, does it make it " S+V+O+C+O+O", or " S+V+O+C+C+C"
or the Two Os and Two Cs simply belongs to the Complement "**to avoid**",
so the sentence still follows the S+V+O+C structure?

Comment: I'd say *answering the teacher's question* is a ***gerund noun***. Syntactically the same as using a more straightforward noun in, for example, *He managed to **avoid the obstacle***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *He could [not [bring himself [to avoid [answering the teacher's question]]]].*

The kind of analysis you’re asking about is only appropriate for simple canonical clauses.

Catenative constructions like this one are far too complex to be analysed in simple SVOC terms, since there are a number of embedded subordinate clauses, as bracketed,  functioning as internal complements.

The subject is *he* and the verb phrase *could not bring himself to avoid answering the teacher's question* is the predicate.

Within the predicate VP is the embedded clause:

*not bring himself to avoid answering the teacher's question*,  which functions as complement of *could*.

Within that clause is the embedded clause:

*to avoid answering the teacher's question*, which functions as complement of *bring*.

Within that clause is the further embedded clause:

*answering the teacher's question*, which is complement of *avoid*, and has *the teacher’s question* as object of *answering*.

The noun phrase *himself*, which intervenes between the two verbs *bring* and *avoid*, is the syntactic direct object of *bring*, and the semantic (understood) subject of the clause *to avoid answering the teacher's question*.

Answer (score 1):

The whole "avoid answering the teacher's question" is the complement, in which the verb is "to avoid" and the object of *that* verb is the gerund phrase "answering the teacher's question".